# How to change the delimiter to sort a dataview in c#

Tags: c#, sorting, dataview

I want to order my dataTable with more than one cols dynamically I make the string concatenating colName and value ("ASC" or "DESC"), but one of my cols don't have an alias and have in col name a "," and dv.sort get these as end of my col name and don't find the col name. Have any changed the delimiter?

PD: Order by more than one col.

```
dv.Sort = "FUNCTION(ASDASD,2) DESC"
FUNCTION(ASDASD,2) = COL NAME
```

Result:
DON'T FIND THE COL NAME "FUNCTION(ASDASD."

Comment: "but one of my cols don't have an alias" - can you not give it an alias.  If it's just returning from a SQL statement, that would be easy to add. Or else, you can manually set the ColumnName when you create your datatable.

Answer (score 0):

I have done these and it worked:

```
 var orderedQResultados = from resultado in dataSet.AsEnumerable()
                                             orderby true
                                             select dataRow;
                    //Ordenacion
                    foreach (Object object in listObjects)
                    {
                        if (oIQ.TextQuery.ToUpper().Contains(object.Columna.ToUpper()))
                        {
                            if (object.Value.ToUpper().Equals("DESC"))
                                orderedQResultados = orderedQResultados.ThenByDescending(row => row[object.Columna]);
                            else
                                orderedQResultados = orderedQResultados.ThenBy(row => row[object.Columna]);
                            dataSet.Clear();
                            dataSet.Merge(orderedQResultados.CopyToDataTable());
                        }
                    }
```